# Why does "hay" have no pronoun?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, verbos, pronombres, haber

The Spanish word **hay** means **there is/are**, however it comes from the present indicative *impersonal* third-person for of the verb *haber*.

When constructing most impersonal phrases such as "*one must*" - "*se debe*", you take the impersonal pronoun "se" and follow it with the verb in the third-person (e.g. "debe").

Why does *hay* not follow the pattern of other impersonal formations?

Is this down to its [etymology](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hay)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't have anything to do with its etymology, although it's an interesting one. It's just that *[haber](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jv4Frsm%7CJv5KhSK)* is an impersonal verb *per se*. Follow the previous link and look for the meanings marked as "impers.". You need to use *se* when using a non-impersonal verb (such as *deber*) in an impersonal sentence.

The meanings of *haber* in such sentences are these ones:

> 8. impers. Estar realmente en alguna parte. *Haber veinte personas en una reunión. Haber poco dinero en la caja.*
> 9. impers. Hallarse o existir real o figuradamente. *Hay hombres sin caridad. Hay razones en apoyo de tu dictamen.*

There are [many impersonal verbs](http://dirae.es/palabras/?q=impers.), most of them being related to the weather: *llover, nevar, granizar, atardecer, diluviar, brisar*, and so on. None of them need the *se* to form sentences.

Note that you still need to use *se* with *haber* when the verb is not used in any of its impersonal meanings:

> Se ha de venir bien vestido.

In the case of the last example, the meaning is not impersonal:

> 2. aux. U. con infinitivo que denota deber, conveniencia o necesidad de realizar lo expresado por dicho infinitivo. *He DE salir temprano. Habré DE conformarme.*

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up! I would just like to ask, is there any official word for the "hay" form of the verb, it comes, etymologically from "ha" (he/she/it has) + I (from the Latin ibi - there). Is this a reusable formation or is it unique to hay? For example, frivolously, could I say "da" (he/she/it gives) + I to form "it gives me there"?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey no, it's not a reusable formation. The _hay_ form is unique, I can't think right now of any other verb with a similar construction.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey at best it'd be called the *forma especial impersonal*.  Note that interestingly you don't use *hay* when referring to time, despite it being equally as impersonal: *cinco años ha, hice algo* (and not **cinco años hay hice algo*)